# How to replace value of keys and parameters from a url?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to replace keys from a url with multiple keys and parameters

**Url Example**

localhost/{id1}/xyz/{id2}?parameter={parameter}

**My Current Implementation:**

```
export const formatString = (url: string, args: any) => {
  let str = url;
  for (let key in args) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + key + '\\}', 'gi'), args[key]);
  }
  return str;
};
```

This implementation only works for single key.

**Expected Result**

localhost/DYM123/xyz/AXE123?parameter=ABCD

Is there a solution to replace all the keys and parameters at one go?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This one only works for single key

Comment: could you add example? how do you expect and what is the result of the above code?

Comment: Added an expected result to the question @Jacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```js
const url = 'localhost/{id1}/xyz/{id2}?parameter={parameter}';
const args = {id1: 1, id2: 2, parameter: 'foo'};

const formatString = (url, args) => {
 return url.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/ig, (_, key) => args[key]);
};

console.log(formatString(url, args));
```

In TypeScript:

```js
export const formatString = (url: string, args: any) => {
    return url.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/ig, (_, key) => args[key]);
};
```